# ¿Como validar la cantidad de digitos ingresados en un input type number?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, validación

Estoy utilizando jvalidator de bootstrap pero no logro validar la cantidad de digitos ingresados en un input type number

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label coLor-letter" for="textinput">No Vin</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="line" type="number"   class="form-control input-style" data-error=""  maxlength="12" >
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad `maxlength`sólo funcionará con `<input type="text">` ya que limita el número de caracteres en una cadena de texto.

Para un `<input type="number">` se utilizan las propiedades `max` y `min`.

Ejemplo, sí quieres que sólo se pueda introducir un valor entre 1 y 999:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene mucho tiempo, sin embargo en un proyecto de esas fechas , dejo de funcionar el type number, no marca error alguno, y si deja ingresar numeros mayores al señalado en el max.

Answer (score 1):

Creo la solución es tan sencilla como calcular el `length` del `value` del campo en cuestión:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input" value="my_value" >

var digitos = document.querySelector('#my_input').value.length
```